# Build Error in Appodeal, Unity, Facebook project

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, appodeal

I have made a mobile game with appodeal ads and facebook plugin.
I get this error while building the project.

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.

This error just happens when these plugins are both integrated.
It works correctly when only one plugin is integrated.

And there is no same `.jar` files in my project.

facebook 7.9.4

appodeal 2.8.3-190917

I think there is a problem in PlaySevicesResolver. Any idea?

Comment: Could you post whole error message please? There are multiple reasons that could lead to this error. Does it say that you have reached 65535 methods limit? If it does You have to remove some libraries [ you can delete some of appodeal providers and use Appodeal.disableNetwork("deleted provider name") ] or try building multidex application using build.gradle